Cannot edit an existing data factory in synapse
I have a synapse workspace with several pipelines with data factories. Today I have noticed that existing data factories that are running correctly I cannot see the details when I edit them
I attach two examples, one that is working and the other that I cannot see the detail
If I click source code, I can see and it seems correct.
Example ok, With configuration
Example ko, Without configuration

Can you refresh and check once. This seems to be non-reproducible for me

You have mentioned that it is fine when you check the source code of the pipeline or activity. Use the source code of the pipeline and build another pipeline. Run the pipeline and check if it is working or not. If it is working, then there is nothing wrong with the pipeline flow or activity.
So, this issue might be because of the following reasons:

It might be a temporary glitch for the UI, try to refresh the page and check again. But make sure to publish the modified pipeline before refreshing because refreshing will delete the unpublished changes.
Cache of the browser might also be one of the reasons for this. Clear all browser cache and re-open the pipeline and make sure your browser is up to date. Also, check the same pipeline in another browser.
Try to change the zoom size of the activities and then re-open. Sometimes, high zoom size of the activities may cause this.

